# Android Studio Firebase extract query problems

Tags: java, android, json, firebase, android-studio

My friend and I are just creating an android app with Android Studio and Firebase, we're asking for users who register to add some pieces of information, like their interests and we're saving them in realtime-database. Unfortunately, when we try to extract all the list of interests from the database we can't set up a filter that is like: extract all keys that start with the letter "B".

Can someone please help us? Thanks a lot :)

Here is the database root:

```
Database-name
{
  "Interests" : {
    "Badminton" : "Badminton",
    "Batman" : "Batman",
    "Batteria" : "Batteria",
    "La cipolla" : "La cipolla",
    "Pagliacci" : "Pagliacci"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries) you can use this:

```
dinosaursRef.orderByKey().startAt("b").endAt("b\uf8ff").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
    System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getKey());
  }

  // ...
});
```

So, `startAt()` and `endAt()` will filter those values for you. Alternativly, you can filter returned values on your own by checking if `substring(0, 1)` is equal to `"b"`.